# Datetimepicker using the Bootstrap change

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Datetimepicker date and time format display like this **11/01/2013 12:00 AM**.
But i need like this **Mon Jun 22 2015 14:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)** Please help me.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker4' />
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Which plugin? What code? Blah blah?

Comment: using the jquery and bootstrap.@PraveenKumar

Comment: I have answered with the format you need to use.

Comment: still not working.@PraveenKumar

Comment: Oka fiddle chesthava plz?

Comment: @vamsikr There are several different widgets called `datetimepicker`. Could you point to exactly which one you're using?

Comment: Bootstrap datetimepicker.@blgt

Answer (score 0):

Your format for this would be:

```
D M d yyyy g:i:s a
```

Initialize with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
            format: 'D M d yyyy g:i:s a'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where did you get this format? The documentation pointed to moment which uses [different format options](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Comment: OP hasn't specified what the plugin that is being used. So, I *assumed* it to be [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), as it was mentioned by the OP.

Comment: That's `datepicker`, not `datetimepicker`

Comment: I know... Almost all the dtp's follow the same.